# WPF Binding to DataSets

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have the following relationship defined as a strongly typed dataset:

[image: Three way relationship]

Let us assume that the Window's datacontext is bound to the current row of the User table.

I'd like to have a DataGrid bound so that a list of checkboxes are displayed one for each of the items in the ConfigOption table where we assume that ConfigOption_Description is a string value containing the name to be displayed alongside the checkbox.

The user has one record in the UserConfig table for each of the configuration options applicable to them. The Configuration value (ConfigValue) is a boolean value. If no record appears in the table it is assumed the same as if the value is set to false - that is, the user doesn't have this option enabled.

I know that I can bind my window's data context to my current User and using a converter that passes the UserID of the current user I can determine which of each of the options should be enabled for the current user (and thus which checkboxes should be checked).

I'd like to know if there is a way by which I can define my CollectionViewSource:

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsUsers" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsUserConfig" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsConfigOptions" />
  </Window.Resources>
  <DataGrid DataContext="cvsConfigOptions">
    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=[ConfigOption_Description]}" IsChecked="????" />
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

I know I can bind the IsChecked using a converter, but surely there has to be a way to bind these objects utilizing the tables and the relationships already defined between them.

Just a hypothetical abstract example (which doesn't work) would be:

```
<DataGrid>
  <Checkbox Content="Option1" IsChecked="CurrentUser.Option1.ConfigValue" />
  <Checkbox Content="Option2" IsChecked="CurrentUser.Option2.ConfigValue" />
  <Checkbox Content="Option3" IsChecked="CurrentUser.Option3.ConfigValue" />
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. `ConfigValue` is a bool value? also, Binding has nothing to do with foreign keys. Please clarify

Comment: A work around for your problem could be found by Creating a View which provides you the required details like ConfigOption_Description and ConfigValue and Use that view to create you CollectionViewSource and Bind it to the Datagrid CheckBox. Hope this helps